# How to use Web3.py with Solidity Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix, web3.py

I want to use Web3.py with Solidity Remix. I select environment as External Http Provider.

[image]

After that, It shows information like this.

[image]

It login to Metamask then it shows an error like this

```
Error while connecting to the provider, provider not connected
```

The Metamask also did not connect.

[image]

How to use Web3.py with Solidity Remix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an execution node at the address provided (127.0.0.1:8545). I don't know where Web3.py comes in here but the reason why you can't connect is you have not mentioned that you've deployed infrastructure of any kind of that address, and so obviously there's nothing to connect to.

Web3.py is also a client so it does many of the same things as Remix. You can use both, but you can't use both on each other. Web.py is not a node implementation. Imagine that Remix and Web3.py are both power cords that you need to plug in. The node is the socket on the wall. Right now you're holding two power cords and wondering why they don't produce electricity.

"Provider" is a inclusive term that includes private nodes, public nodes, self-hosted nodes, shared nodes, etc. Clients connect to them in order to work. You can find a lot of places offering free node access including through the http protocol so you can use Web3.py or Remix with it. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but nobody - you or anyone else - can use Web3.py as a provider that you can plug into Remix.